# Trouble updating Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, software-updates

Addendum2- added to respond to the followup
comment/question of terdon.

---

Addendum added to respond to the
comment/question of terdon.

---

I am having trouble updating / upgrading Linux Mint.  7 days ago, from the command line, I issued a `sudo apt update -y` and a `sudo apt upgrade -y`.  Both commands appeared to run okay, with no problems.

This evening I encountered a problem.  Checking my version:

```
$ cat /etc/issue
```

shows

```
Linux Mint 20.3 Una \n \l
```

This evening I issued the command:

```
steve@steve-H97-D3H:~$ sudo apt update -y
```

and it gave

```
steve@steve-H97-D3H:~$ sudo apt update -y
Hit:1 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu focal InRelease
Ign:4 http://packages.linuxmint.com una InRelease
Hit:5 http://packages.linuxmint.com una Release
Hit:7 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                       
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]                                       
Hit:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease   
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Fetched 336 kB in 11s (29.7 kB/s)  
steve@steve-H97-D3H:~$ . 65%
```

After waiting 1 minute, I used `Ctrl-C` to restore my command line.

Then, I issued

```
steve@steve-H97-D3H:~$ sudo apt upgrade
```

which produced

```
steve@steve-H97-D3H:~$ . 65%
```

Again, I used `Ctrl-C` to restore my command line.

Then, I invoked the Update Manager gui.  It showed the message `processing updates` at the bottom of the gui and showed the spinning arrow, indicating that it was busy.

How do I investigate this and remedy the problem, so that I can (once again) periodically update/upgrade my system?

---

**Addendum**
Responding to the comment/question of terdon.

Although I am a retired programmer, my knowledge of internal Linux processing is very superficial.  I have never before seen the symptoms listed below, and I would like to understand them.

If these symptoms represent Linux Mint's way of indicating that there is nothing to update or upgrade, then that is fine.  It is certainly different than how Fedora used to communicate this.

My blind, uneducated speculation, which could easily be wrong, is that that there is a problem accessing one of the repositories.  If this is a temporary problem that will dissipate on its own, within a few days, then that does not represent a problem for me.  However, I need for someone very knowledgeable in this area to evaluate the symptoms and definitively explain them:

- The `update` command seemed to *finish* with a 65% message, that seemed to spill over into the next command line.
  I have never seen this type of behavior before.  Normally, when a command finishes, a command prompt is returned, with nothing on that line. Alternatively, if the command gets *hung up*, for any reason, a command prompt is not returned.  
  What caused this type of unusual behavior? 
  Also, what is the significance of the *65%* message?  65% of *what*?
- The `upgrade` command similarly finished.  So, similar questions are raised with respect to this command.
- The `update manager` gui seems to *hang*.  In fact, experimenting, I left this gui running overnight, and in the morning, the gui still had not *finished*.

I don't think that the unusual behavior of the update manager gui is coincidental.  I think that there is some underlying anomaly that explains all three symptoms.

In order for me to keep my system healthy, I need to understand the cause of the anomaly.

---

**Addendum-2**
Responding to the followup comment/question of terdon.

> Can you confirm that simply pressing Enter also clears it, just like your Ctrl+C did? That the GUI hing hangs is more worrying.

No, I can't confirm what simply pressing `Enter` *would* have done.  I just tried to re-create the situation, so that I could press `Enter`.  On this particular attempt, both the update process and the upgrade process appeared to run smoothly.  The results are shown at the end of this Addendum-2.  So, this *portion* of the anomaly does appear to be a temporary (remote) respository problem that was resolved.

Assuming so, I don't really need to investigate what caused the temporary *remote* problem.

However, after all of the upgrades had been processed, I then re-invoked the `update manager` gui.  As before, the update manager gui showed the message `processing updates` at the bottom of the gui and (as before) the gui also showed the spinning arrow, indicating that it was busy.

> Please also try running sudo -i` to get a root shell, and then in that shell try running apt update.

I held off on this, since the updates and upgrades appeared to go through okay.  The only pending anomaly is therefore the `update manager` gui, which I never use anyway.  If that particular issue persists, after I run updates next Sunday night, then I will do a cold boot next Monday morning, and then re-invoke the `update manager`.  Then, if needed, I will initiate a separate unix.stackexchange posting.

Executing the `update` command:

```
steve@steve-H97-D3H:~$ sudo apt update -y
```

gave:

```
[sudo] password for steve:         
Hit:1 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                    
Ign:5 http://packages.linuxmint.com una InRelease                                         
Hit:6 http://packages.linuxmint.com una Release                     
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu focal InRelease    
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]      
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages [687 kB]
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages [1,589 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [1,946 kB]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [278 kB]      
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [15.6 kB]            
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [924 kB]               
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [391 kB]
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [20.9 kB]        
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [24.5 kB]            
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [8,468 B]      
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [944 B]  
Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata [592 B]
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [7,984 B]
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [30.5 kB]               
Get:26 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main i386 Packages [461 kB]                   
Get:27 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [40.7 kB]
Get:28 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [10.6 kB]
Get:29 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [66.2 kB]
Get:30 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,464 B]
Fetched 6,841 kB in 12s (562 kB/s)                                    
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
8 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
steve@steve-H97-D3H:~$
```

Executing the `upgrade` command:

```
steve@steve-H97-D3H:~$ sudo apt upgrade -y
```

gave:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-5.4.0-100 linux-headers-5.4.0-100-generic linux-headers-5.4.0-104
  linux-headers-5.4.0-104-generic linux-headers-5.4.0-99 linux-headers-5.4.0-99-generic
  linux-image-5.4.0-100-generic linux-image-5.4.0-104-generic linux-image-5.4.0-99-generic
  linux-modules-5.4.0-100-generic linux-modules-5.4.0-104-generic linux-modules-5.4.0-99-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-100-generic linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-104-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-99-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  curl firefox firefox-locale-en isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common libcurl3-gnutls libcurl3-gnutls:i386 libcurl4
8 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 64.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 1,407 kB disk space will be freed.
Get:1 http://packages.linuxmint.com una/upstream amd64 firefox amd64 102.0+linuxmint1+una [62.3 MB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 libcurl3-gnutls i386 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.12 [260 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libcurl3-gnutls amd64 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.12 [232 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 isc-dhcp-client amd64 4.4.1-2.1ubuntu5.20.04.3 [246 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 isc-dhcp-common amd64 4.4.1-2.1ubuntu5.20.04.3 [44.9 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 curl amd64 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.12 [161 kB]          
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libcurl4 amd64 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.12 [235 kB]      
Get:8 http://packages.linuxmint.com una/upstream amd64 firefox-locale-en amd64 102.0+linuxmint1+una [697 kB]    
Fetched 64.2 MB in 7s (9,254 kB/s)                                                                              
(Reading database ... 685528 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-firefox_102.0+linuxmint1+una_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking firefox (102.0+linuxmint1+una) over (101.0.1+linuxmint1+una) ...
Preparing to unpack .../1-libcurl3-gnutls_7.68.0-1ubuntu2.12_amd64.deb ...
De-configuring libcurl3-gnutls:i386 (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.11) ...
Unpacking libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.12) over (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.11) ...
Preparing to unpack .../2-libcurl3-gnutls_7.68.0-1ubuntu2.12_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libcurl3-gnutls:i386 (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.12) over (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.11) ...
Preparing to unpack .../3-isc-dhcp-client_4.4.1-2.1ubuntu5.20.04.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking isc-dhcp-client (4.4.1-2.1ubuntu5.20.04.3) over (4.4.1-2.1ubuntu5.20.04.2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../4-isc-dhcp-common_4.4.1-2.1ubuntu5.20.04.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking isc-dhcp-common (4.4.1-2.1ubuntu5.20.04.3) over (4.4.1-2.1ubuntu5.20.04.2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../5-curl_7.68.0-1ubuntu2.12_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking curl (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.12) over (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.11) ...
Preparing to unpack .../6-libcurl4_7.68.0-1ubuntu2.12_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcurl4:amd64 (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.12) over (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.11) ...
Preparing to unpack .../7-firefox-locale-en_102.0+linuxmint1+una_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking firefox-locale-en (102.0+linuxmint1+una) over (101.0.1+linuxmint1+una) ...
Setting up firefox (102.0+linuxmint1+una) ...
Setting up isc-dhcp-client (4.4.1-2.1ubuntu5.20.04.3) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/apparmor.d/sbin.dhclient ...
Setting up libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.12) ...
Setting up libcurl3-gnutls:i386 (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.12) ...
Setting up firefox-locale-en (102.0+linuxmint1+una) ...
Setting up libcurl4:amd64 (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.12) ...
Setting up isc-dhcp-common (4.4.1-2.1ubuntu5.20.04.3) ...
Setting up curl (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.12) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.9) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for mintsystem (8.5.3) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24+linuxmint1) ...
steve@steve-H97-D3H:~$
```

Comment: What is the problem? It sounds like something is adding a `\r` to the end of your commands, but the update should have worked. Enter would have cleared your prompt just like Ctrl+C did.

Comment: @terdon Please see the Addendum that I added to the end of my posting to respond to your comment/question.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. My first guess is that the 65% is just something that was printed to standard error, and is just an artifact. This is because what you show is that the prompt _has_ been displayed: ` steve@steve-H97-D3H:~$ . 65%`. Can you confirm that simply pressing Enter also clears it, just like your Ctrl+C did? That the GUI hing hangs is more worrying. Please also try running `sudo -i` to get a root shell, and then in that shell try running `apt update`, do you see the same issue? If not, that tells us it is something to do with your user.

Comment: @terdon Thanks for your time and attention.  I have added an Addendum-2 to respond to your followup question.  In summary, the results *suggest* that the original problem was a temporary problem with a remote repository.  I will re-investigate the *pending* `update manager` anomaly next week and post a new unix.stackexchange question, if needed.

Comment: Ah, great! OK, in that case I will close this question as non-reproducible, since it seems to have sorted itself out. If you need to figure out the GUI issue a new question, as you suggested, would indeed be better. Fingers crossed that everything's OK now!

Comment: Can you explain why this would be useful reopened? As far as I can tell there was no problem and it went away on its own, and such things are explicitly off topic here and even have their own close reason. A mod can't post an answer since only you know what really happened, and mods aren't anything special or somehow more knowledgeable than non-mods (I am so mod, so I know!).

Comment: @terdon At MathSE, if a posting is closed then it is subsequently deleted.  When that happens, the posting becomes generally unavailable to subsequent users.  I am assuming that a similar mechanism is in place at UnixSE.  I strongly suspect that the problem was caused by either [1] network traffic routing in and out of the repository or [2] Mint developer (temporary) programmatic error.  In either event, the situation will very plausibly recur.  ...see next posting

Comment: @terdon When that happens, and the next user (like me) with less than superior knowledge of linux internals investigates, they will hopefully see this (inactive) posting.  When they do, they will realize that the most productive thing that they can do is wait 24-48 hours, and then re-try.  Hopefully, the next such user will further realize that only if the 2nd attempt fails, do they need to research further, perhaps initiating a new UnixSE question, among other things.  Therefore, my intent is that this posting serve as a valuable log of events, that future users can use as a guide.

Comment: I hear you, but I still don't think there was a problem. The command line issue you mentioned is just a display thing and the other was went away. We don't want to have posts lying around if they're about problems that disappear by themselves because we consider them unlikely to be of help. This is supposed to be a Q&A site and if the answer is "it goes away" then it isn't very useful. I'll ask some of the other mods to have a look but I really don't see how this will be helpful or can be considered on topic.

Comment: Maybe another way to see this is that it doesn't appear to be a "UNIX/Linux problem". If the problem was either "[1] network traffic routing in and out of the repository or [2] Mint developer (temporary) programmatic error." then there's not a whole lot of value in an answer that says "wait 2 days", unless it's something that's happening to Mint users frequently.